# Multithreading with STL container

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I have an unordered map which stores a pointer of objects. I am not sure whether I am doing the correct thing to maintain the thread safety.

```
typedef std::unordered_map<string, classA*>MAP1;
MAP1 map1;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexA)
   if(map1.find(id) != map1.end())
   {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexA); //already exist, not adding items   
   }
   else
   {
       classA* obj1 = new classA;
       map1[id] = obj1;
       obj1->obtainMutex(); //Should I create a mutex for each object so that I could obtain mutex when I am going to update fields for obj1?
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexA); //release mutex for unordered_map so that other threads could access other object
       obj1->field1 = 1;
       performOperation(obj1); //takes some time
       obj1->releaseMutex(); //release mutex after updating obj1
   }
```

Comment: I don't see any areas where deadlock could occur, unless it's somehow possible for another thread to get to obj1 before `->obtainMutex()` is created.  In other words, as long as you lock `mutexA` before accessing `map1` for read or write, you should be OK.  However, I think I would move the `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexA)` up one line as long as the `id` for the map doesn't change based on the contents of the objects in it.

Comment: Are the objects stored in your `map` accessed via multiple threads for updates to `field1`? Isn't it better to make the objects thread-safe themselves instead of cluttering---sorry for that word---your code with `obj1->obtainMutex`?

Comment: when I was working with MSVC, some years ago, we had a multi-threaded version of the standard libraries. If you can get a thread-safe version of the stl, it can at least spare you the per-container mutex `mutexA`

Comment: also, when you are adding an entry, and thus modifying the container structure, you should not allow even the read-only access to it. So it seems that a read-write lock is in place here. Again, the thread-safe library should save you all this.

Answer (score 2):

Several thoughts.

If you do have one mutex per stored object, then you should try to create that mutex in the constructor for the stored object.  In other words, to maintain encapsulation, you should avoid having external code manipulate that mutex.  I would convert "field1" into a setter "SetField1" that handles the mutex internally.

Next, I agree with the comment that you could move `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexA);` to occur before `obj1->obtainMutex();`

Finally, I don't think you need `obtainMutex` at all.  Your code looks as if only one thread will ever be allowed to create an object, and therefore only one thread will manipulate the contents during object creation.  So if I consider only what little code you've shown here, it does not seem that mutex-per-object is needed at all.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see with the code is that it will lead to problems especially when exceptions occur.

```
   obj1->obtainMutex(); //Should I create a mutex for each object so that I could obtain mutex when I am going to update fields for obj1?
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexA); //release mutex for unordered_map so that other threads could access other object
   obj1->field1 = 1;
   performOperation(obj1);
```

If performOperation throws an exception then obj1->releaseMutex(); will never get called thus leaving the object locked and potentially leading to deadlocks sometime in the future.
And even if you do not use exceptions yourself some library code you use in performOperation might. Or you might mistakenly sometime in the future insert a return and forget to unlock all owned locks before and so on...

The same goes for the pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock calls.

I would recommend using RAII for locking / unlocking.

I.e. the code could look like this:

```
   typedef std::unordered_map<string, classA*>MAP1;

   MAP1 map1;

   Lock mapLock(&mutexA); //automatci variable. The destructor of the Lock class
   //automatically calls pthread_mutex_unlock in its destructor if it "owns" the 
   //mutex

   if(map1.find(id) == map1.end())
   {
       classA* obj1 = new classA;
       map1[id] = obj1;

       Lock objLock(obj);
       mapLock.release(); //we explicitly release mapLock here

       obj1->field1 = 1;
       performOperation(obj1); //takes some time
   }
```

I.e. for a reference for some minimalistic RAAI threading support please refer to "Modern C++ design: generic programming and design patterns applied" by Andrei Alexandrescu ([see here](http://books.google.com/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=Andrei+Alexandrescu+Lockable&source=bl&ots=YQjH1qUg2U&sig=HDdiKvUb1klz7IljF3jkDTO_oo8&hl=en&ei=GhwsTZKYHZCLswaKx83mBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Other resources also exist ([here](http://www.relisoft.com/win32/active.html))

I will try to describe in the end one other problem I see with the code. More exactly, the problem I see with having the obtainMutex and releaseMutex as methods and calling them explicitly. Let's imagine thread 1 locks the map, creates an object calls obtainMutex and unlocks the map. Another thread (lets call it Thread 2) gets scheduled for execution locks the map obtains an iterator to the map1[id] of the object and calls releaseMutex() on the pObject (i.e. let's say due to a bug the code does not attempt to call obtainMutex first). Now Thread 1 gets scheduled and calls at some point releaseMutex() also. So the object got locked once but released twice. What I am trying to say is that it's going to be hard work making sure the calls are always correctly paired in the face of exceptions, potential early returns that do not unlock and incorrect usage of the object locking interface. Also Thread 2 might just delete the pObject it obtained from the map and erase it from the map. thread 1 will then go on an work with an already deleted object.

When used judiciously RAII would make the code simpler to understand (even shorter if you compare our versions) and also help a lot with some of the problems I enumerated above.

Comment: I think that you could move the `Lock mapLock(&mutexA);` inside the `if`?

Comment: @davka. I guess not, because the if accesses the map (makes a find). Assuming that map1 is an object shared between multiple threads and that another thread might attempt to insert in the map while the thread is in map1.find(id) the map access should be guarded. One could create a scope that contains the lock and the following if that would then ensure the mapLock gets released.Or could explicitly release it after the if. I lazily assumed that the function doing the map access ends after the if ;-)

Comment: of course you're right. I myself proposed something like this in my answer :) Well, I said I was a bit rusty on multy-threading...

Answer (score 0):

Thought of combining my comments into an answer:

**1)** When you are adding an entry, and therefore are modifying the container, you should not allow read access from other threads, as the container may be in a transition between legal states. Complementary, you should not modify the container when other threads are reading it. This calls for the use of `read-write lock`. The pseudo-code is something like:

```
set read lock
search container
if found
  release read lock
  operate on the found object
else
  set write lock
  release read lock
  add entry
  release write lock
endif
```

(it's been some time since I've done multi-threaded programming, so I may be rusty on details)

**2)** When I worked on MSVC some years ago we used the **multi-threaded** (i.e. thread-safe) version of the standard libraries. It could save you all this trouble. Didn't bother (yet) to check if thread-safe std exists also on gcc/Linux.